# Popovers misplaced in some HTML elements

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working in a project where I use jQuery (~2.1.1), Bootstrap (~3.3.1), AngularJS (~1.3.4), Angular-ui-bootstrap (~0.12.0), and some more libraries. I have a small problem which is related with the **popover** directive of the `angular-bootstrap` library. This little problem is that **many** of the popovers are misplaced, so probably I am forgetting about something.

From the documentation and even personal tests ([Plunker Example Ex. using angular 1.3.4](http://plnkr.co/edit/87c7cbML9uJFlDJCSmwT?p=preview)), the popover should look aligned to the center of the HTML element, and the arrow of it should touch the element, like this:

[image]

The problem is that in my application the popover gets misplaced somehow (In this case only vertically the offset is noticeable, so it's not touching the element), as you can see next:

[image]

Another example (which is the most noticeable) is with a dynamic generated list using `ng-repat`, as you can see in the next picture:

[image]

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 sidebar-offcanvas"
         id="sidebar-left" role="navigation">
        <div class="list-group shadow-bottom" id="sideMenuTitle">
            <span class="list-group-item list-group-item
                disabled offcanvas-title" style="text-align: center">
                <strong>Metrics</strong>
            </span>
            <a popover="{{metrics_messages[$index]}}" popover-popup-delay="450" popover-trigger="mouseenter"
               popover-placement="top" popover-animation="true" ng-repeat="m in metrics" ui-sref="{{m.sref}}"
               class="list-group-item"
               ng-click="selectMetric(m)" ng-class="{active: m.selected}">{{m.caption}}</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

PS: I included `ui.bootstrap` to the "global" angular module, as they suggest [Angular Bootstrap Site](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/2996) pull request may address your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the version where this post was made, after that version they fixed this problem.